# Are there more effective ways for a wizard to recover frequent and diverse ability damage other than this specific pair of magic items?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class, d20-system

The Prestige Class Metaphysical Spellshaper (BoEF, p.81) has the ability to spontaneously cast metamagic spells, at the cost of suffering 1 ability damage per spell level the metamagic improves the base spell (and all the damage must be to the same stat at the same time).

The easiest way to go about avoiding this would be a Restoration spell (though it requires an additional DC 20 caster level check), but that only appears on the Cleric and Paladin spell lists. Going 10 ranks into Rainbow Servant is an option so you can cast Restoration on yourself, but it requires a lot of time and leveling. Another would be to carry a couple of Rods of Bodily Restoration (MIC p.173) or Orbs of Mental Renewal (MIC p.167). But is this the most effective way? Or are their other ways to do this?

Note: Books allowed are the BoEF itself and all the D&D 3.5e works. I'm looking for preferably a spell, but a magic item can also work. And no, convincing another party member to prestige into Divine Prostitute (BOEF, p.88) or haul one around as a follower is not an option.

Comment: What's the full title for BoEF?

Comment: @MatthewNajmon Book of Erotic Fantasy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### *Strongheart vest* provides “Ability Damage Reduction”

The *strongheart vest* soulmeld from *Magic of Incarnum* reduces the ability damage you take by 1. Requires the Shape Soulmeld feat, which requires Con 13. Which anyone should have that isn’t undead.

### Naberius, the Grinning Hound provides Fast Ability Healing

If you have a single level of the binder class, you can bind Naberius, the Grinning Hound to get the ability to heal ability damage at a rate of 1/round instead of 1/level.

### *Rod of bodily restoration* is the most cost-effective item to heal ability damage

The *rod of bodily restoration* from *Magic Item Compendium* has 3 charges per day, can spend 1-3 charges to heal physical ability scores. Does not work for mental scores.

## That said, metaphysical spellshaper is a ridiculously broken class

Metaphysical spellshaper is like an incantatrix on crack. Incantatrix, one of the highest-power prestige classes in the game. And you could have levels in both. I **strongly** recommend against playing this class. It is not well designed, and you *will* be vastly more powerful than almost anyone else could ever be.

Comment: Does Naberius heal 1 damage point per round, or 1 damage point to every damaged ability? So if you have 2 damage to Strength and 2 to Dexterity, does it take 2 or 4 rounds to fully heal?

Comment: @ThomasJacobs I'm away from my books; there are details about all three items that I forget and intend to add when I get home. That is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Potions of lesser restoration only cost 300 gp, so those might be worthwhile, especially at low levels.  If you have Use Magic Device scrolls are 150 for Lesser Restoration and 800 for the full version.

If custom magic items are allowed, a slotless item of at-will restoration would cost about 164,000 gp.  A weapon-slot item with the same abilities would cost 123,000 gp, and an item of the appropriate body slot (probably "cloak, cape, or mantle") would cost only 82,000 gp.  If you would prefer the more powerful Greater Restoration the costs become 864,000 gp, 648,000 gp, and 432,000 gp respectively.  Class, race, alignment, and/or skill restrictions can further reduce these prices as normal.

As 9th level Cleric-Sorcerers, Couatls are capable of knowing Restoration.  Depending on how your GM runs summoning, you may be able to summon Couatls to do this for you.  This could be achieved either by way of 9th level pearls of power (if you are a high enough level) or, if custom magic items are allowed, much more permanently by an item of at-will Summon Monster IX (If you need to ask the price, this item is too expensive for you).  Couatls are also valid cohorts/followers if Leadership/Epic Leadership is allowed, in which case you most certainly are able to decide its spells known.

If you are merely looking to *prevent* ability damage, rather than removing it, you can do so easily and much cheaper; The spell Sheltered Vitality grants temporary immunity to all ability damage, and would cost 120,000 gp, 90,000 gp, or 60,000 gp for a slotless, inappropriately slotted, and appropriately slotted item respectively.  You can also acquire immunity to some kinds of ability damage by being undead or a construct.

Comment: I didn't think of Sheltered Viality, actually. What would be an appropriately slotted item for that spell?

Comment: @ThomasJacobs Ask your DM.  I'd probably go with "cloak, cape, [or] mantle" again if I was feeling particularly RAW, otherwise I'd go for shields.  Your DM might instead reasonably go for "Amulet, brooch, medallion,
necklace, periapt, [or] scarab" or, of course, robe (it's the catch-all).

Comment: @ThomasJacobs Third-party (and, hey, let's be honest, a lot of first-party) stuff could be better written in spots, and the metamagic manipulation supernatural ability is one of those spots. It'd probably be a good idea to clear with the DM first that immunity to ability damage still allows the use of that special ability. Immunity to ability damage is easy (e.g. a *talisman of undying fortitude* (*MIC* 188) (8,000 gp; 0 lbs.) grants immunity to ability damage for 3 rounds/day); healing ability damage is, at least, a bit more tedious.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking taking 10 levels of a prestige as a viable solution, you could always take Leadership instead (http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#leadership) and just get a cleric cohort.  Seems less extreme to me and their caster level would scale better against the check (vs the items which likely wouldn't).  Then heal, greater restoration etc become (eventually) available to you as well.
Make your own prostitute!  (never thought I'd type that:P)

I agree however with comments in the other answer and think investigating items/spells that make you immune to the damage is worthwhile.
I only skimmed the class but it seems that losing the ability damage is conscious (when you use metamagic) and not forced, so you should know the hit is coming and could potentially pre-buff if the item/spells found are not quickened.
This syncs with the concept above as it gives you access to non-personal cleric spells and potentially crafting (if item access is limited).